# Workflow Foundation 4 read ReadWriteComplexDataProperties

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to deserialize the ReadWriteComplexDataProperties column and I found the following article [How to: Deserialize Instance Data Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/how-to-deserialize-instance-data-properties) but I can't seem to get it to work for the ReadWriteComplexDataProperties column. What do I need to change to make it work for that column?

Answer (score 0):

That Howto does state that the code does not work for the ReadWriteComplexDataProperties.

Please post your code and show where it fails.